# Optimizing queries vs. adding indexes

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan

I have this very old and SLOW query that I am trying to optimize, but I am not sure I can do anything to it, but add more indexes on columns involved in WHERE, JOIN and ORDER BY.

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 400 jobticket.jobnumber, jobticket.typeform, jobticket.filename, jobticket.req_number, jobticket.reqd_del_date, jobticket.point_of_contact, jobticket.status, jobticket.DapsDate, jobticket.elpod, job_info.IDOrderMaskedStatus, job_info.job_status, job_info.SalesID, job_info.location, job_info.TOMetadataID 
FROM jobticket WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN job_info WITH (NOLOCK) ON job_info.jobnumber = jobticket.jobnumber 
WHERE  
(
    NOT(
        (jobticket.status = 'Complete' OR jobticket.status = 'Completed') 
         and (job_info.job_status = 'Actualized' OR job_info.job_status = '' 
              OR job_info.job_status = 'Actualized Credit Billed' 
              OR job_info.job_status = 'DWAS Actualized' OR job_info.job_status = 'DWAS Actualized Credit Billed'
             )
        )  
    or 
    ((SELECT COUNT(job_status) AS Expr1 FROM tblConsolidatedBilling AS tblConsolidatedBilling_1 WITH (NOLOCK)  
      WHERE  (job_status <> 'Actualized' 
      AND  job_status <> 'Actualized Credit Billed') 
      AND (master_jobnumber = jobticket.jobnumber)) > 0) 
) 
and (jobticket.status != 'Waiting Approval' or (jobticket.status = 'Waiting Approval' and jobticket.DPGType is null))  
and jobticket.typeform <> 'todpg'  
and ((job_info.isHidden <> 1 or job_info.isHidden is null) and job_info.isInConcurrentRelease is null)  
and job_info.deleted != '1' 
and jobticket.status != 'New Job'  
and jobticket.status != 'PRFYCLSFD'  

ORDER BY 
job_info.expediencyLevel DESC, 
jobticket.jobnumber DESC
```

Execution Plan:
[image: execution plan]

In all honesty I don't know what to do with this query.

Should I add individual nonclustered indexes on all columns involved in WHERE JOIN and ORDER BY?

There are many indexes on these tables, but I am not sure whether they are helpful in this query:

[image]

Comment: Step one I'd start cleaning up some of those indexes.  A lot of them are duplicates and are just slowing your system down.  And of those remaining some are "mostly" duplicates .. master_jobnumber vs master_jobnumber, billnumber, seq_num for example.  You probably don't need both.

Comment: Any chance you can simply provide the `CREATE TABLE` scripts ( with indexes ) for your two tables?  Your key look-ups are at least part of your problem, but it will be difficult to tune your query, if it's even possible at all, using just the information provided in the screenshots.

Comment: Might help a little, but you could have numeric codes in reference tables rather than all those string comparisons - slightly less efficient than integer comparisons. However, I agree strongly with the posters above - you appear to have way too many indexes which could be confusing the optimiser and slowing  you down.

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole lot of looping going on
Give this a try
The exists will be faster then count
And bring stuff up into the join can help the optimizer

```
SELECT TOP 400 jobticket.jobnumber, jobticket.typeform, jobticket.filename, jobticket.req_number, jobticket.reqd_del_date, jobticket.point_of_contact, jobticket.status, jobticket.DapsDate, jobticket.elpod
     , job_info.IDOrderMaskedStatus, job_info.job_status, job_info.SalesID, job_info.location, job_info.TOMetadataID 
 FROM jobticket WITH (NOLOCK) 
 JOIN job_info  WITH (NOLOCK) 
       ON job_info.jobnumber = jobticket.jobnumber 
      and jobticket.typeform <> 'todpg'  
      and (    (job_info.isHidden <> 1 or job_info.isHidden is null) 
            and job_info.isInConcurrentRelease is null 
          )  
      and job_info.deleted <> '1' 
      and jobticket.status not in ('New Job', 'PRFYCLSFD') 
      and (     jobticket.status != 'Waiting Approval' 
            or (jobticket.status  = 'Waiting Approval' and jobticket.DPGType is null) 
          )         
WHERE jobticket.status    not in ('Complete','Completed') 
   or job_info.job_status not in ('Actualized','','Actualized Credit Billed','DWAS Actualized','DWAS Actualized Credit Billed') 
   or ( exists ( SELECT job_status AS Expr1 
                   FROM tblConsolidatedBilling AS tblConsolidatedBilling_1  WITH (NOLOCK)  
                  WHERE job_status not in ('Actualized', 'Actualized Credit', 'Billed') 
                    AND master_jobnumber = jobticket.jobnumber ) 
      )           
ORDER BY job_info.expediencyLevel DESC, jobticket.jobnumber DESC
```